# Service NgbModal not unknown

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular8

running into another issue in my starting app.

I installed the ng-bootstrap component to easier access bootstrap related components without using jquery.

this is the content in my app.module.ts

```
...
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
...
@NgModule({
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    ToastyModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    BackendModule
...
```

In the Backend Module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {BackendRoutingModule} from './backend-routing.module';
import {MainComponent} from "./main/main.component";
import {SharedModule} from "../shared/shared.module";
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {TestComponent} from './test/test.component';
import {NgbModalModule, NgbModule, NgbTabset, NgbTabsetModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import {ToastyModule} from "ng2-toasty";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbTabsetModule,
    NgbModalModule,
    BackendRoutingModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    ToastyModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
})
export class BackendModule {
}
```

In the Component I wanted to start opening an modal to create an entry:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  closeResult: string;

  /**
   *
   * @param modalService
   */
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
  }

}
```

But here I get the follwoing error message:

Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TestComponent: (?).

I followed the integration according to:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

But I can't get it work. What am I missing?

I am Using the newest angular 8 and cli app.
As package manager I'm relying on yarn.

Comment: I think that the problem can be that you `import {NgbModalModule, NgbModule, NgbTabset, NgbTabsetModule}`, left as `import {NgbModalModule, NgbTabset, NgbTabsetModule}`, or import all the module  `import {NgbModule}` -and include in the import,the rest of code look me like ok

Comment: Hi thank you for you help.

Comment: It worked without changing code. it is strange. Had to reboot my system and right after it everything worked like a charm. ???????